# Is it possible to redefine a function at runtime in python?

Tags: python, function, overriding

I have a small project for my numerical analysis class where I have to evaluate several functions using different methods so that we can compare the performance and efficiency of these methods. While most of my code runs fine, one of the function we must evaluate is the cube root of x. Since python utilizes the principal root, this causes the methods to diverge. I want to be able to use one function name so that I don't have to copy paste everything when I have to use the cube root function. Is there a way to have a function be redefined at runtime? I do not have any classes implemented so I do not want introduce a class if possible. Thanks.

EDIT:
my main function is this:

```
def main():
    global func, derv
    func = 'pow(x,2)*sin(x)'
    derv = '2*x*sin(x)+pow(x,2)*cos(x)'
    print('evaluating x^2sin(x): ')
    newton(-0.2,10**-4,20)
    bisection(-0.9,1,10**-4,20)
    fixed(-0.2,10**-4,20)

    func = 'pow(x,2)*sin(x)-x'
    derv = '2*x*sin(x)+pow(x,2)*cos(x)-1'
    print('evaluating x^2sin(x)-x: ')
    newton(-0.2,10**-4,20)
    bisection(-0.9,1,10**-4,20)
    fixed(-0.2,10**-4,20)

    func = 'pow(x,1/3'
    derv = '(1/3)*pow(x,(-2/3)'
    print('evaluating cuberoot(x): ')
    newton(-0.2,10**-4,20)
    bisection(-0.9,1,10**-4,20)
    fixed(-0.2,10**-4,20)
```

and my function/derivate functions are:

```
def function(x):
    y = eval(func)
    return y

def function(x):
    y = eval(func)
    return y
```

the function and derivate functions are used in other functions to evaluate numbers for the numerical methods i'm using. For the cube root function, since the methods will have the values bouncing between negative and positive numbers, I would have to create a function or something in order to return a valid value.

Comment: Yes, have you tried?

Comment: Does that mean you’re using `eval`, or…? Please show the relevant code and the problematic input/output.

Comment: @Ry- added more details and the relevant code

Comment: Functions are first-class objects; define the appropriate function and pass it as an argument to `newton` et al as an argument instead of messing around with global variables and `eval`.